# Cakephp: share logic between Model and Controller

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

Note: I'd found out this open question [What's the correct place to share application logic in CakePHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064883/whats-the-correct-place-to-share-application-logic-in-cakephp) which is very similar, but since the questions is open and dead since 2010 I think is better to create a new one.

I have some common functions that I'd like to use without reapeating them in several parts on my Cakephp app, concretely in Model and Controller. These functions are pretty simple, like reparsing a string to remove strange characters, so I can apply them in different points and I dont want to mantain several copies from same code.

The first thing I thougth was to use a Component but there is not recommended to use them in Models, I also see that is possible to use a plugin but I think is too much big to mantain.

Maybe I could just put these funcions in the bootstrap file, but I don't like so much this solution.

Which is the better way to achieve this logic sharing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Dave and burzum said, if it's related to data, put it in a Model/Behavior.

But if it's more general, you can simply put it in an external lib and then use this lib.

```
Lib/MyLib.php
<?php

class MyLib {
    public static function doThis() {}
}

app/Controller/FooController.php
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
App::uses('MyLib', 'Lib');

class FooController extends AppController {
    public function someAction () {
        MyLib::doThis();
    }
}

app/Model/Foo.php
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
App::uses('MyLib', 'Lib');

class Foo extends AppModel {
    public function someMethod () {
        MyLib::doThis();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is more close to what I'm looking for actually, I'm using cakephp 1.3 but I can use the App:uses equivalent anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Rule of thumb: If it's data manipulation it should be done in a model.

If you want to share the logic between models: Make it behavior.

This way you can attach it to the models that need the functionality. In Cake3 you can use traits as well.

Comment: my common logic is pretty simple, so i'd like to share it between models and controllers that's why behavior or controller doesn't fit exactly

Comment: I assume that you know that you can call a model method from a controller? So where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Could put them in your AppModel.  That way, you could access them from any Model (which means you could also access from any Controller).

If you put it in the AppModel, it will just automatically BE available to all models.

And you could access them via any controller by running it through a loaded model:

```
// in any Model
$this->whateverMethod();

// in any Controller
$this->MyModel->whateverMethod();
```